# gnome-terminal works only with sudo

Tags: python, user-permissions, gnome-terminal

I know that the following issue will probably demand from you to invest more time than other issues in order to fix it, but if it's interesting you, please do it. It might be useful for you too :)

I tried to configure a nice 'application' called `iface`. It allows to use a terminal of Linux VM in Windows' command prompt. Like this:

[image]

The scripts are here: https://github.com/gynvael/iface
There are detailed video instructions of how to configure it (in Polish, but you can understand from the video itself) [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHGysGcRFFI).

Anyway, when trying to run the command `gnome-terminal` with my (not root) Linux's user - I encounter the following error:

`Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached`

But, when trying to run it with `sudo gnome-terminal` or with root user (like in minute 1:52:30 in the video) - it works and the command prompt is opened.

Actually, the command (in Windows) `if-l-cmd.py /` (as you can see in minute 1:56:09) worked, but after I restarted the computer - it doesn't work any more. I tried to install everything from the beginning in another computer, and encountered the same problem.

Help will be appreciated!